# How to get data from JSON with Alamofire?

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to get data from `JSON` with `Alamofire` but the data come with ["Chris Martin"] and not Chris Martin. Check this image

[image]

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func botaoSalvar(_ sender: Any) {

    let nomeUsuario = self.campoUsuario.text;
    let cpf = self.campoCPF.text;
    let senha = self.campoSenha.text;

    let param = ["nome": nomeUsuario, "cpf": cpf, "senha": senha, "method": "app-set-usuario"]
    var _: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
    let url = "http://easypasse.com.br/gestao/wsCadastrar.php"

    Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:param,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            //print(response)
            let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
            let idusuario =  json["usuario"].arrayValue.map({$0["idUsuario"].stringValue})
            let nome =  json["usuario"].arrayValue.map({$0["nome"].stringValue})
            let cpf =  json["usuario"].arrayValue.map({$0["cpf"].stringValue})

            print(idusuario)
            print(nome)
            print(cpf)

        case .failure(let error):
            print(0,"Error")
        }
    }
```

How should i fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I realize English is not your first language, but any chance you can rephrase your question?

Comment: Sorry, i changed "and" for "e"... Maybe that why you didn't understand

Comment: It doesn't look like a Swift specific issue, but with whatever JSON parsing Alamofire does. It looks like you are directly asking for a mapped array of values in `usuario`, so the JSON parsing in Alamofire is honoring that.